# Xilinx ISE Board, trying to make two clocks (ZYBO FPGA)

Tags: clock, timing, xilinx-ise

In the [reference manual](http://www.digilentinc.com/data/products/zybo/zybo_rm_b_v6.pdf) for the ZYBO board that I am using, it informs me that I have up to four clocks I can use. However, when I look through the UCF file, I can only find one of them.

Considering that the ISE tools might know where it is, I used the Timing Analyzer to try to get the system to generate a pin LOC that I could use, this was a fialure though.

Then I had the idea to use the PlanAhead tools to try and see if the tools would again generate a UCF file with the needed clock pin locations. Again this failed.

Have I misunderstood the manual? Is there only one clock pin available to me?

Here is the excerpt in question (12 Clock Sources):

> The ZYBO provides
>   a 50 MHz clock to the Zynq PS_CLK input, which is used to generate the
>   clocks for each of the PS subsystems. The 50 MHz input allows the
>   processor to operate at a maximum frequency of 650 MHz and the DDR3
>   memory controller to operate at a maximum of 525 MHz (1050 Mbps). The
>   ZYBO Base System Design configures the PS to work properly with this
>   input clock, and should be used as a reference when creating custom
>   designs.
>
> The PS has a dedicated PLL capable of generating up to four reference
>   clocks, each with settable frequencies, that can be used to clock
>   custom logic implemented in the PL. Additionally, The ZYBO provides an
>   external 125 MHz reference clock directly to pin L16 of the PL. The
>   external reference clock allows the PL to be used completely in
>   dependently of the PS, which can be useful for simple applications
>   that do not require the processor.
>
> The PL of the Zynq-Z7010 also includes two MMCM’s and two PLL’s that
>   can be used to generate clocks with precise frequencies and phase
>   relationships. Any of the four PS reference clocks or the 125 MHz
>   external reference clock can be used as an input to the MMCMs and
>   PLLs. For a full description of the capabilities of the Zynq PL
>   clocking resources, refer to the “7 Series FPGAs Clocking Resources
>   User Guide” available from Xilinx.
>
> Figure 13 outlines the clocking scheme used on the ZYBO. Note that the reference clock output from the Ethernet
>   PHY is used as the 125 MHz reference clock to the PL, in order to cut the cost of including a dedicated oscillator for
>   this purpose. Keep in mind that CLK125 will be disabled when the Ethernet PHY (IC1) is held in hardware reset by
>   driving the PHYRSTB signal low.

[image: Diagram given in the RM]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your descrption:

There is one external reference clock (125 MHz) and 4 internal reference clocks from the ARM part. These 4 clocks are not accessable as a real pin but via the ARM-FPGA bridge. If I'm right this component in called `PS7`.

Additional resources;
- [UG585 - Zynq-7000 - Technical Reference Manual](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf) chap. 25.7 PL Clocks -> schematic for PL clocks

Additionally, you can use the clock modifing blocks (MMCM or PLL) to derive new clocks from these 5 'inputs'.

Comment: Please provide citations?